# Seleccionar diferentes columnas de una arreglo

Tags: python, python-3.x, array

[image: arreglo]
Estoy tratando de seleccionar dos diferentes columnas de un arreglo en python mi arreglo tiene 19 columnas solo eh encontrado la forma de seleccionar dos columnas continuas

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido a SOes, por favor introduce los datos como código, no como imagen. Así ayudarás a que la gente no tenga que escribirlo a mano para reproducir tu problema. También deberías incluir el código que dices haber probado y que solamente devuelve columnas contiguas, para que nos hagamos una idea de lo que quieres conseguir realmente.

Answer (score 0):

puedes concatenar dos columnas con numpy de la siguiente manera

```
col1 = matriz[:,0]
col1 = matriz[:,-1]

nueva_matriz = np.c_[col1, col2]
```

Eso concatena la primera y ultima columna